# Gerrit issue with patchsets

Tags: git, gerrit

I have an issue with my local gerrit installation.
I have installed gerrit on localhost, and I did that successfully. But now when I'm submitting patches (even with git `commit --amend`), they are displayed in gerrit as new changes, and not as new patch sets.

How can I fix that?

I have found something interesting that executing this might fix the issue: `scp -p -P 29418 localhost:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks`  but this results in a `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

Thanks,
Arkde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes just like you suspected, adding the commit message hook will resolve this issue.  See the [change id documentation](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.7/user-changeid.html).  As for your permission denied error - maybe add `username@` in front of `localhost`?  If that still fails, try the `curl` command used in the documentation.

Comment: Adding the username fix the problem :) didn't think about that. Thanks Brad